# Algorithmic Complexity of Estimators

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I am interested in evaluating the algorithmic complexity of an estimator of the form:

$$\hat{\theta} = \text{argmin}_{\theta} \;\; Q_n (\theta)$$

where $Q_n(\theta)$ denotes some objective function of interest (e.g. - log likelihood) computed on a sample of length $n$. $\hat{\theta}$ is assumed to be obtain through some numerical optimization methods (typically a stepwise procedure). Under this setting, how could I compute the algorithmic complexity of $\hat{\theta}$?

I am really not sure if this makes sense but here is how I approach this problem:

- Suppose that the numerical procedure used to compute $\hat{\theta}$ requires $S$ steps to converge.
- Assume that there exist a deterministic function, say $f(p)$, where $p$ denotes the dimension of $\theta$ such that $S \leq f(p)$ and that $f(p) < \infty$ for $p < \infty$.
- Assume that $\mathcal{O} (Q_n(\theta)) = g(n)$ for all $\theta$.
- Then $\mathcal{O}(\hat{\theta})$ is simply given by

$$\mathcal{O}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathcal{O}(Q_n(\theta) S) = g(n),$$

since $p$ is assume to be fixed (and bounded). This seems really too simple... Any comments would be more than welcome. Thank you very much.